# Does registering event handlers consume much resources?

Tags: jquery

Does the amount of resources needed to register an event handler grow proportionally to the number of elements in the selected object?

For example in the following:

```
$('.emoji').click( ..... );
```

If there are 4000 elements with the class emoji, would the memory used up in the browser be significantly higher?

Comment: I don't know how jQuery implements its events, but I am pretty sure they *must* be doing some sort of [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). So, pretty sure the answer to your question, is "no" but I am not posting it as an answer because it is based on an assumption on my part

Comment: Event Handlers consume resources. How much is "much" for you? Why not try to create an example and see the values?

Comment: `much` = that needed by 4,000 separate select options.  Where/how to see the values?